# ubuntu mail server settings and /etc/hosts file

Tags: ubuntu

This is my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain                   localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-server.xx.com                ubuntu-server
193.77.xx.xx   mail.xx.com                         mail

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

is this correct configuration for my mail server. I am behind router so i don't know if is ok to use my IP for mail.xx.com and 127.0.0.1 for localhost

problem is that i can receive mail but when i send it i get

```
Oct 17 21:29:32 ubuntu-server postfix/smtpd[2453]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Oct 17 21:29:32 ubuntu-server postfix/smtpd[2453]: warning: my.router[192.168.1.1]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Oct 17 21:29:34 ubuntu-server postfix/smtpd[2453]: warning: my.router[192.168.1.1]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

EDIT:

mabye is problem some port. i foward this ports.

```
POP3 - port 110
IMAP - port 143
SMTP - port 25
HTTP - port 80
Secure SMTP (SSMTP) - port 465
Secure IMAP (IMAP4-SSL) - port 585
StartTLS - port 587 
IMAP4 over SSL (IMAPS) - port 993
Secure POP3 (SSL-POP) - port 995
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
message_size_limit = 0
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination =
myhostname = mail.xx.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.xx.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.xx.com.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/maps/alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/maps/domain.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/maps/user.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

saslfinger -c

```
version: 1.0.4ostfix Cyrus sasl configuration Ä
mode: client-side SMTP AUTH

-- basics --
Postfix: 2.9.3
System: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

-- smtp is linked to --
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00d3a000)

-- active SMTP AUTH and TLS parameters for smtp --
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes


-- listing of /usr/lib/sasl2 --
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root   4096 okt 14 15:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 72 root  root  12288 okt 14 15:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root      1 maj  4 06:17 berkeley_db.txt
-rw-r-----  1 root  root    701 okt 14 15:18 saslpasswd.conf
-rw-r-----  1 smmta smmsp   885 okt 14 15:18 Sendmail.conf

-- listing of /etc/postfix/sasl --
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 okt 11 18:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 okt 12 06:59 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root  241 okt 11 18:55 smtpd.conf


Cannot find the smtp_sasl_password_maps parameter in main.cf.
Client-side SMTP AUTH cannot work without this parameter!
```

Comment: Update your question with the output of `postconf -n` and [`saslfinger`](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/saslfinger/).

Comment: i updated my question. thx

Answer (score 0):

The output of `saslfinger` is rather self-explanatory:

```
Cannot find the smtp_sasl_password_maps parameter in main.cf.
Client-side SMTP AUTH cannot work without this parameter!
```

Create a file (e.g. `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`, make sure only root has access to that file!) and enter the hostname of the relayhost as well as your credentials:

```
mailrelay.example.com    username:password
```

Use `postmap` to create a map from the textfile:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Then point `$smpt_sasl_password_maps` to it (in `main.cf`):

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Reload Postfix.

For a more detailed explanation see [this HOWTO](http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html) written by Patrick Koetter.